# Creating a dynamic key for an object at creation with ASC2.0 compiler

Tags: actionscript-3

t's always been a bit of an irritation for me (I do more than a bit of coding in Python too, and the way that deals with dict/object types is much clearer and better), but prior to ASC2.0, I was always able to get around it with,

```
var fooS:String = 'foo';
var barO:Object = { ('' + fooS): 'bar' };
for (var key:String in barO)
   {
      trace(key, barO[key]);
   }
```

(prints 'foo bar')

But trying to do that in ASC2.0 results in an

```
 '(' is not allowed here
```

Error.

Any ideas?

I know that I can always set a key with a dynamic variable through square bracket access, but any time I have to do

```
var fooS:String = 'foo';
var a:Object = {};
a[fooS] = 'bar';
```

I find it fairly overkill and wasteful.

Comment: Less characters is overkill and wasteful? How comes you like the dirty ('' + ) syntax so much?

Comment: Oh no, I definitely don't prefer the ('' + ) syntax, I'd much prefer as3 to treat {myvar: "1"} as an object that has one key which is whatever the variable myvar contains, unfortunately there's no way to do that.
The biggest irritation is when setting the key of an object is within a function.  With ASC2.0, there's no one-liner way to set the value of a variable in an object.  I prefer the dirty syntax to not being able to do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

AS3 comforms to ECMA 4th edition.
In this edition there is no "inline" way to generate keys.
As you said, the only the following code may be used:

```
var object:Object = {};
object['some' + 'dynamic' + 'key'] = 'some value';
```

The only alternative is to create your own API, perhaps like the following:

```
var map:Map = new Map().put('some' + 'dynamic' + 'key', 'some value');
```

where Map.put() returns "this"